# How do you make more than 700,000 points?

Tags: stardunk

In [Stardunk](http://godzilab-games.com/games/stardunk/), I'm wondering how to reach more than 700,000 points in contests. I usually get the ball with the long aimer and perform like 40-45 extra clean shot.

This seems to be the best setting to me. But i really cannot get how people could get 900,000 or even 1,000,000+ how is that possible?

Comment: What game is this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your getting clear up to 700,000 you wont find any 'try this advice'... Chances are you have the right idea but just need to work on your timing.  As with any other game that takes timing: its all about practice, being in the zone, and just plumb getting lucky!

The more often you play, the better your sense of timing will be and the more clean shots you can pull off. Some day, perhaps over a delicious cup of morning coffee, you may break the million point mark.

Comment: Actually I score all possible extra clean shots and still get maximum 700.000. How is that possible to reach more?

Comment: @Charlie I have found numerous exploitable gliches and hacks for the game through google searches.  Its very possible the users you are seeing have cheated in some way

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **speed**. Not only that, you need all extra clean but also need to improve your speed. My best score with Luckyball was 1,2xx,xxx and I can still see there's room for improvement on my speed.